# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio causing system freeze

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008

I'm experiencing very slow response from MSSMS and it causes other applications to slow down. Specially Skype crashes after few seconds from opening MSSMS, showing an error called "Disk I/O Error". I'm regularly using few applications (Sublime text, MS Word, Firefox, Outlook, Skype and one or two other apps) simultaneously. The system works fine when MSSMS is not in use! But as soon as MSSMS is opened, all the apps start to freeze (MSSMS also responds very slow). This problem has been there for about a week now (I haven't installed any apps or haven't made any changes to the system during that time).

-- System Specifications --

- Processor: Core i3 (3.1 GHz)
- RAM: 4 GB
- OS: Windows 7 Professional (64 bit)
- Free space in C drive: ~ 100 GB
- MS SQL Server 2008 R2
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version - 10.50.1600.1

I've tried to find a reason for this but there are no helpful information in the web! There are some solutions suggested (in forums and in Skype Support pages) for the Skypes' "Disk I/O Error", all of which I tried but **does not solve** the problem.
Has anyone faced the same senario? (and hopefully) knows a solution?

---

**Systems Log**

I don't have much knowledge in interpreting the System Log, but I think the Critical and Warnings are not helpful. But there are lots of Error logs which might be useful.

[image: System Log Summary]

In source Kernal-General there are few similar errors saying "An I/O operation initiated by the Registry failed unrecoverably.The Registry could not flush hive (file): `<some file>`"

In source atapi also there are few similar errors --> "The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Ide\IdePort0." (all errors has occurred in 'IdePort0')

In Application Error, there are several errors logged, and following is the latest one.

[image: Application Error log]

Both the Errors which has occurred today is similar (to this one). As it is from Ssms.exe, I guess this is relevant to the cause of problem. But as I said above I can't understand what it means!

Comment: When you look at your System event log, filtered for Critical/Error/Warning events only (no Informational events), what do you see?

Comment: @MilesErickson I've edited the question. Unfortunately I don't have permission to upload the images. Can you please up vote this question (so that I can upload it). Or else I'll just type everything. :)

Comment: You're providing good information, so I'll upvote you! :-) I wonder if there are actually bad sectors (recoverable or not) in the files that MSSMS is reading, which is what causes the controller errors (and subsequent system instability, eg Skype reporting I/O issues). It might be worthwhile to check the SMART status of the drive; see [these](http://superuser.com/questions/29240/how-can-i-read-my-hard-drives-smart-status-in-windows-7) [questions](http://superuser.com/questions/157266/when-to-stop-using-a-hard-drive-what-rules-software-apply) for more info on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue appears to be caused by a problem with your hard drive and/or controller.

Suggestions:

1. *Of course* you have a full, current, backup and you've tested the restore process to make sure that it is actually usable. If not, back up your system immediately.
2. Run a file system check including a scan for bad sectors. Keep in mind that bad blocks visible to the operating system on a contemporary hard drive are a *very bad sign* indicating that the drive should be replaced ASAP.
3. Verify that all disk-related drivers (including RAID drivers and controller firmware) are up to date.
4. Replace the drive/cable with known good parts, and restore from backup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've added more details to the problem. Can you please check it?

Comment: Still seems consistent. You might want to try a tool like [Disk Checkup](http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm) to review whether the drive is reporting SMART errors.

Comment: I'll do that. And perhaps replacing the SATA cable + trying a different port on the motherboard as well. 
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Added the two screen shots of log summary and application error log.

Comment: I did a disk check (for all the partitions) with 'automatically fix file system errors' and 'scan for and attempt for recovery of bad sectors' optioned ticked. There were some bad sectors in C: drive and were fixed. I've then used the system for about an hour now; no issues! So far so good. Hope this will permanently fix the problems.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect this strategy. You might want to review the drive's SMART info for an indication of how extensive the problem is; sometimes bad blocks are an indication that a drive is getting ready to fail.

Comment: If the drive reported bad sectors, replace it, its going to be downhill from here.

Comment: Yep. If it were my drive, my bias would be toward replacing it immediately. Drives are cheap.